# if-else equivalent via linq-to-sql query in where clause c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, where-clause

Basically I wanted to have an if-else statement in my linq to sql statement.

```
var query = from d in database
            if(x == y) {
                where d.Attr = x
            }
            else {
                 where d.Attr = y
            }
            select d;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is just an example, and that you aren't actually using that check, because if you are, it will always resolve the case for the value of 'y'.  

x=4, y=3  use the else (3)
x=3, y=3  use the if (3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't that just the same as

```
var query = from d in database
            where d.Attr == y
            select d;
```

Your situation (or a similar, more realistic one) can be handled with a simple conditional in the where clause.  For more complex queries you can use the extension methods to build up a query implementing conditionals pretty easily or use a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create arbitrarily complex conditions.

```
var query = db.Table;
if (x == y)
{
   query = query.Where( d.Attr == z );
}
else
{
   query = query.Where( d.Attr == t );
}

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Foo>()
                                .And( f => f.Attr == y )
                                .And( f => f.Attr == x )
                                .Or( f => f.Attr == z );
var query = db.Foo.Where( predicate );
```

Comment: Hahah well I gave a bad example. Thanks for the answer, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Supposing, you meant `==` and not `=`:

```
from d in database
where (x == y && d.Attr == x) ||
      (x != y && d.Attr == y)
select d;
```

Comment: if x and y are not parameters of `database`, it would be better to move the if outside the LINQ query

Comment: Since `x==y` will have the same truth value for all elements of `database`, there is no reason to translate both `d.Attr == x` and `d.Attr == y` to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think I may have misunderstood what you wanted to do.

I'm not sure if the ? (ternary) operator will work in Linq to SQL, but try this:

```
from d in database select (x == y) ? x : y
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt

```
if(x == y) { 
                where d.Attr = x 
            }
```

be the same as

```
if(x == y) { 
                where d.Attr = y 
            }
```

if x==y?

so couldnt you just use

```
where d.Attr = y
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, assuming you meant `==` and not `=`:

```
var query = from d in database
            where (x == y ? d.Attr == x : d.Attr == y)
            select d;
```

However, this is logically equal to the following:

```
var query = from d in database
            where d.Attr == y
            select d;
```

Because, if `x == y` is true, then `d.Attr == x` and `d.Attr == y` **will** be equal.

Answer (score 0):

var query = from d in database where (x == y)? d.Attr = x : d.Attr = y select d;